# Manage onclick event of element dynamically generated inside div rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, odoo

In my Odoo module, I generate with qweb a row divs that can contain different elements like checkbox, texarea, input etc.

When I load data from DB. I know the id of the element row and assign it to the div row that can contain the elements.

I need to know when a user click to a certain input inside a precise div row.

Code:

```
                   <!-- Load the section lines of the section_ids choosed-->
                    <t t-foreach="checklist_lines" t-as="check_line">
                        <div class="row section_line" t-att-id="check_line.id" style="border-top: 1px solid black; padding:2px;">

                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                                <span t-esc="check_line.name"/>
                            </div>
                            <t t-if="check_line.answer_yes_type">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 col-md-1" style="display:inline;">
                                    <!-- TODO if yes is true check if have subsections and load it-->
                                    <input type="checkbox"
                                           t-att-id="str(check_line.id) + 'answer_yes_type'"
                                           t-att-name="str(check_line.id) + 'answer_yes_type'"
                                           t-att-value="check_line.answer_yes"
                                           style="margin:10px;">Yes
                                    </input>
                                </div>
                            </t>
                            <t t-if="check_line.answer_no_type">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 col-md-1">

                                    <input type="checkbox"
                                           t-att-value="check_line.answer_no"
                                           style="margin:10px;">No
                                    </input>

                                </div>
                            </t>
                            <t t-if="check_line.answer_undecided_type">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">

                                    <input type="checkbox"
                                           t-att-value="check_line.answer_undecided"
                                           style="margin:10px;">Undecided
                                    </input>

                                </div>
                            </t>
                            <t t-if="check_line.answer_text_type">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                                    <textarea type="text"
                                              t-att-value="check_line.answer_text"
                                              style="margin:10px; width:100%; height:100px;"
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </t>
                            <t t-if="check_line.answer_value_type">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
                                    <input type="text"
                                           t-att-value="check_line.answer_value"
                                           style="margin:10px;"
                                    />
                                    <t t-if="check_line.answer_value_uom_id">
                                        <span t-esc="check_line.answer_value_uom_id.name"/>
                                    </t>
                                </div>
                            </t>
                            <t t-if="check_line.order_id">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 col-md-1">
                                    <a t-attf-href="/my/orders/{{check_line.order_id.id}}?{{keep_query()}}">
                                        <span t-esc="check_line.order_id.name"/>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </t>

                        </div>
                        <br/>
                    </t>
```

With `t-att-name` and `t-att-id` I set a dynamic id to change elements inside `row` following this rule `id=row_id + name_of_view`.

For now, I have this jQuery function that intercept the user click and return the id of the clicked row:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $('.section_line').on("click", function () {
            var checklist_line_id = $(this).attr('id');
            alert(checklist_line_id);
        });
    });
```

But like that I need to check all element inside div and check if the user change something.

I would like to know if the user for example click on the checkbox inside div row with id 1.
So i have `row=1` and `checkbox id = 1answer_yes_type`.... and i would like to know if the user clicked the id 1answer_yes_type....or the element 1answer_value etc...

How can I manage that?

Comment: Can't you just use find? $('.section_line').find("div").on("click", function(){alert($(this).attr('id'))})

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.clicked').find("div").on("click", function(){
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
     var valueofcheckbox = $(this).find('input')[0].value;
    var textofcheckbox = $(this).first().text();
    alert('div id: '+ id + ' checkbox value: '+ 
       valueofcheckbox + ' text of checkbox: ' +textofcheckbox);
       })
   });
```

working link :

> https://codepen.io/sidhanshu28/pen/MXjVzo

let me know if this helps, or you need to know anything else